# django tables 2 accessing m2m

Tags: django, django-tables2, m2m

I have two models:

```
class Hi(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=2)


class Hello(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    his = models.ManyToManyField(Hi)
```

I am trying to render `Hello` model. Thus I have `tables.py` like this:

```
class HelloTable(tables.Table):
    his = models.ColoumnField()

    def render_his(self, value):
        hi = []
        for i in value.his.all():
            hi.append(i)
        return (',').join(hi)

     #And the metas
```

I get `ManyToMany has no attribute his`. What's wrong?

Comment: I think `his` is not a Hello instance. We need the code of your call to `render_this`

Comment: I have only this codes.

Comment: try to replace `for i in value.his.all():` with `for i in value.all():`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should solve your issue and simplify your code a little bit:

```
def render_his(self, value):
    return (', ').join(list(value.all()))
```

or

```
def render_his(self, value):
    return (', ').join([x.name for x in value.all()])
```

if you want a specific attribute instead of the `unicode` representation of your `Hi` objects.

You are getting the error because `value` is a `ManyToManyField` instance, not a `Hello` instance.